# For Next Elseif Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to make a loop that says starting in row 11 and going down by counting the # of active cells/formulas with values and making that variable named `i`, if range `AV & i` is `0` then set range `AV:BY = 0`. Or else, if range `BV & i = 0` then set range `BZ:DC & i = 0`. And if none of that is true, then set range `A2:DK2` = range `A2:DK2` = `Range("A" & i & ":DK" & i).Value` And `Range("DL" & i & ":FY" & i) = Range("DL2:FY2").Value` Then end if and continue the loop. I feel like I'm so close but I keep getting a mismatch error on that last line of code:

```
'Loop that runs all members through the calculator
'then saves their calculated CECL back in MemberInfo tab
Sheets("MemberInfo").Select
Dim y As Integer
y = Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).row

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown))
Counter = Rng.count

Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Range("AV11", Range("AV11").End(xlDown))
Counter2 = Rng2.count

Dim Rng3 As Range
Set Rng3 = Range("BZ11", Range("BZ11").End(xlDown))
Counter3 = Rng2.count

'Dim i As Integer
'If Rng2(i).Value > 0 And Rng3(i).Value > 0 Then Sheets("MemberInfo").Select
Sheets("MemberInfo").Select
For i = 11 To Counter
    If Rng2(i).Value = 0 Then
        Range("AV" & i & ":BY" & i).Value = 0
    ElseIf Rng3(i).Value = 0 Then
        Sheets("MemberInfo").Select Range("BZ" & i & ":DC" & i).Value = 0
    Else:
        Range("A2:DK2") = Range("A" & i & ":DK" & i).Value And Range("DL" & i & ":FY" & i) 
    = Range("DL2:FY2").Value  
    End If
Next i
```

I get the error on the Else line ): pls help

Comment: `Range("A2:DK2") = Range("A" & i & ":DK" & i).Value And Range("DL" & i & ":FY" & i) 
    = Range("DL2:FY2").Value` should be 2 separate lines without the `And`

Comment: Also not sure if this was intentional `Counter3 = Rng2.count`  Should it be `Counter3 = Rng3.count`